# ¿Por qué "I am good" se traduce como "soy bueno" y "I am fine" como "estoy bien", teniendo que cambiar el verbo?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, preposiciones, españa, español-neutral

Quiero saber la diferencia entre las palabras `good` and `fine`.

Cuando alguien pregunta **¿cómo está usted?** probablemente respondo algo como `I am good` o `I am fine` en inglés, pero si quiero responder lo mismo en español, los respondería como `soy bueno`  o `Estoy bien`?.

¿Por qué cambia toda la oración? ¿Por qué no sólo las palabras ?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Lo que estás preguntando en realidad es por la diferencia entre los verbos "ser" y "estar". Te recomiendo que busques en el sitio ya que hay multitud de preguntas al respecto que te pueden ayudar con tu problema. Si ninguna de ellas resuelve tu duda, prueba a editar la pregunta y hacerla más concreta, para que los demás seamos capaces de ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Refer to this: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-are-the-differences-between-ser-and-estar-when-to-use-each

Comment: "Soy bueno"? A que pregunta contestarías "soy bueno"?

Comment: When people these days say "I am good" they usually seem to mean "I am fine" at least in southern British English so perhaps you should clarify what you understand by the terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English you only have the verb **to be** but in Spanish we use two different verbs **ser** and **estar**

To fully understand the uses of the verbs **ser** and **estar** you should read [What are the differences between "ser" and "estar"? When to use each?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-are-the-differences-between-ser-and-estar-when-to-use-each)

Regarding you question... First, the question could be **¿Cómo es usted?** or could be **¿Cómo está usted?** and those are two different questions.

The first asks about you as a being (permanent state) and the second asks about your current state (that could be temporary or transitory)

To the first question you could answer **Yo soy bueno** since you **are** *a good person*. The question uses the verb "ser" (¿Cómo **es** usted?) so you answer with the same verb.

To the question ¿Cómo **está** usted? that uses the verb "estar" you should answer with the same verb **Yo estoy bien** since at the *present time* you **are** good/ok/fine.

The above has to do with the meaning of the sentences and the differences between ser and estar but also notice that the use of *fine* in English has some differences to the uses of *good* and *ok* so I'll give some valid translations (that may confuse you more but anyway...)

I'm good = Estoy bien / Soy bueno
I'm fine = Estoy bien
I'm ok = Estoy bien.
He is ok =  El es buena gente
He is a fine guy = El es una persona bueno/correcta
She's fine = Ella está bien / [Ella es bonita](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Damn%20she%20fine)

<sub>I'll think of more examples and continue writing</sub>

Comment: Thanks @DGaleano very nicely expained but I don't understand why someone has voted down my question?

Comment: Neither do I but perhaps it's because it's so similar to the question about ser/estar. Anyway I thought this question deserved a separate answer and so I did.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando traduces traducir "I am good" estás diciendo que siempre eres bueno, como lo es una característica tuya.

Y con eso, cuando traduces "I am fine" es como te sientes en el momento.

En general, si es permanente (como una característica), usas "ser" ; Cuando no es  permanente/es como sientes en el momento, usas "estar" .

[(Bueno y Bien)](https://www.quia.com/quiz/234996.html)
Bueno= good - un adjetivo
Bien= well- un adverbio.

Comment: Oliviaselin.. your answer is partially true but not quite. "I'm good" could be a permanent or transitory state and then can be translated as "Soy bueno" or "Estoy bien" respectively. I'd recomed you to check http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-are-the-differences-between-ser-and-estar-when-to-use-each for a full understanding on the uses of the verbs "ser/estar"