# ¿Por qué se usan "están agotados" y "están vendidos" en lugar de "son agotados" y "son vendidos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Si los billetes de un espectáculo se acabaron, esto no va a cambiar. ¿Entonces por qué el uso de "[estar](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-spanish/are+sold+out)"? ¿Constara un nativo si yo dijera "son agotados"?

Comment: Aparte de las respuestas que te puedan dar aquí, puedes consultar la pregunta canónica [_What are the differences between “ser” and “estar”? When to use each?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/12637) para ver si las respuestas allí dadas te ayudan.

Comment: Acabo de leer esa pregunta que indica @CarlosAlejo y creo que su respuesta es mucho mejor que la mía. De hecho, creo que voy a marcar esta pregunta como duplicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, cuando una cualidad expresa uno de los posibles estados por los que puede pasar algo usamos el verbo *estar*, incluso si ese estado es el final. Por ese motivo decimos *está vivo*, pero también *está muerto*, pese a que este es ya el estado final.

En el caso de la pregunta, los billetes pueden estar disponibles y luego pasan a estar agotados; aunque este último ya es un estado final (dejemos de lado la posibilidad de que haya devoluciones o ampliaciones de aforo), utilizamos el verbo *estar*.

Más que la posibilidad de cambio, lo que indica el uso del verbo *ser* o *estar* es que la cualidad se considere intrínseca o no. Por ejemplo, diríamos *este coche es verde*, pese a que nadie me impide pintarlo de rojo más tarde. Pero el color es una cualidad propia del objeto, no un estado.

Otro ejemplo: puedo decir *la estatería es muy alta*, pero de un objeto situado en el estante superior diría que *está muy alto*; la altura es una cualidad intrínseca de la estantería, pero para el objeto es un estado (podríamos ponerlo en otro lugar más bajo).

Answer (score 1):

La explicación de Gorpik es cierta, pero no creo que sea la más adecuada para esta pregunta.

Lo que pasa es que existen "dos tipos de pasiva": la de proceso y la de resultado. (Aviso: si nos ponemos filológicos perdidos esto quizá no es muy exacto, pero es así como se suele explicar a los estudiantes de ELE.)

La de proceso es la pasiva que hemos aprendido de toda la vida, y se forma con "ser". La de resultado expresa, lógicamente, el resultado, y se forma con "estar".

Las expresiones que mencionas son claros ejemplos de pasiva de resultado: los billetes han sido vendidos (proceso) y, como resultado, ahora están vendidos, están agotados.