# ¿Cuándo debo usar cuál? Ser, estar, ir, haber, hacer, tener

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

I have seen different words used in Spanish expressing the meaning of "be, to be".

> El océano **es** azul. (The ocean is blue)
>   **Estoy** enojada. (I am angry)
>   **Fue** por la lluvia que me mojé. (It was because of the rain that I got wet)
>   **Hay** pimientos en la nevera. (There are peppers in the refrigerator)
>   En invierno **hace** frío. (It's cold in winter)
>   **Tengo** 20 años. (I'm 20 years old)

I'm confused because in English there's only one word *be*, while there's extra words for the same meaning and with the same(?) usage. Is there any rules for choice or do I pick one at random/preference? More importantly, what's the usage of *ir*, *haber*, *hacer* and *tener*?

---

Treating the title as an exception, please don't post an answer full of Spanish or I'll have trouble understanding it.

Comment: I think this question shoud be tagged as **duplicated** because the most common questions in this forum are about differences between **SER** and **ESTAR** verbs.

Comment: Probably the most relevant questions is https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-are-the-differences-between-ser-and-estar-when-to-use-each-cu%C3%A1les

Comment: There seems to be something of value: expressions translated as 'to be' with tener etc.

Comment: I agree with @walen, we already have a question about the differences between "ser" and "estar", and the answer is quite a long one, imagine if we also add other verbs. So you can refer to that question for the first two verbs in the list, and then maybe center your question in when to use "haber", "hacer" or "tener". It will be even better if you ask for a particular verb at a time. But bear in mind that such questions may already been asked here, so try to search for them first. I sincerely encourage you to ask as many questions as you want.

Comment: The last three sentences are all special idiomatic uses of their verbs.  You just have to learn them.  With time you'll get used to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal translation of the verb "*to be*" can only be done with the verbs "*ser*" or "*estar*", depending on context. In some of your examples it was not translated into any of those two, but in others like "*hacer*" or "*tener*". The reason is we are not actually doing a literal translation in such cases, but giving a different sentence that expresses the same idea but from another point of view.

Let's look at your examples one by one.

> El océano **es** azul. (The ocean is blue)

You are describing how the ocean is in terms of color. It is its natural color. If the sea had a different one in a specific point of time, like when he is almost black due to oil spilled on it, you could say "*el mar **está** negro*", and not "*el mar **es** negro*", because it is not always black.

> **Estoy** enojada. (I am angry)

She uses the verb "*estar*" and not the verb "*ser*" because she is not angry all the time, only in a limited period of time. It is a mood that could change.

If you tell a woman "*eres linda*", that means she's generally cute (*linda*). On the other hand, if you say "*estás linda*", it means that she is cute at that moment, and if you consider her always cute, "*estás linda*" means that at that moment she is more than normal, perhaps because of the way she is dressed, the make-up, etc.

> **Fue** por la lluvia que me mojé. (It was because of the rain that I got wet)

By your comments I see that you already realized it. The word "*fue*" is in this case conjugation of the verb "*ser*" and not of the verb "*ir*", so there is nothing strange about the translation.

> **Hay** pimientos en la nevera. (There are peppers in the refrigerator)

Both "*there is*" and "*there are*" are translated into "*hay*" in indicative mode, and into "*haya*" in subjunctive, which are conjugated forms of the verb "*haber*". If we did a literal translation, we should write them as "*allí está*" or "*allí están*" respectively. But in Spanish we express those ideas with the verb "*haber*".

> En invierno **hace** frío. (It's cold in winter)

In the English example you use the verb "*to be*" because you are describing how the climate is. In the Spanish one you use the verb "*hacer*" because you are referring to the effect that the climate makes or produces on an individual. We could also say: "*El clima **es** frío en invierno*". Here the confusion is due to what I mentioned at the beginning: sometimes, in the different languages, we express the same ideas in different senses, and the same thing happens in the following example.

> **Tengo** 20 años. (I'm 20 years old)

In Spanish, the used verb is "*tener = to have*" because we say how many years we accumulated. I's like if we had those years, our existence owns them. The way to ask the age would be literally translated into English as "*How many years do you have?*"

Now let me put another example:

> **Estoy** en el parque. (I'm at the park)

Here we cannot use the verb "*ser*". The distinction here is no longer due to the period of time, but to that when I mean the place where I am, I must use the verb "*estar*". "*Estar*" refers to being located.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between *ser* and *estar* is a confusing one. I hope a native can explain this better. There is also a third verb translated as to be. Roughly:

*Estar*:

- To be located
- To be in a mood
- To be in a state (eg. dead or alive)
- To seem, to evoke feeling

*Haber* in the forms *hay* / *haya*:

- There is / are

*Ser*:

- If not otherwise specified, use *ser*.

The rest of the verbs you quoted don't mean *to be* in their general sense but can be translated as *to be* in the specific contexts you gave.

*Hacer*:

- To do
- To make

*Tener*:

- To have

And finally, the verbs *ser* and *ir* have the same preterite. In the example you gave, *fue* is an inflection of *ser*.

Comment: As a Spanish learner of Finnish origin, I feel you: we don't have a distinction between 'to be', 'there is' and 'have' at a verb level. We use 'olla' and different cases.

Comment: Didn't even notice that! *ir* and *ser* have the same preterit and subjunctive imperfect/imperfect 2/future conjugation!

Comment: My dictionary keeps directing me to *ir* when I'm looking for *fui* / *fue*. Great discovery!

Comment: I believe it to be the only example of such a combined tense. The other forms you mentioned follow from the preterite.

Comment: Though no, the futures are not the same. Eg. the first person singular seré vs iré. EDIT: mea culpa, didn't read that right. The subjunctive futures do match.