# What is the difference between "La película es bien" and "La película está bien"?

Tags: gramática

I'm stuck. What is the difference?

> 1) La película de los Vengadores es bien.

and

> 2) La película de los Vengadores está bien.

I would say both make sense to me. Like if n. 2 is my "humble opinion" about the movie and n. 1 is a more authoritative way to say the same thing.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Just 2 is right in this situation. You may want to read our canonical [What are the differences between “ser” and “estar”? When to use each? // ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre “ser” y “estar”? ¿Cuándo se usa cada uno?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/1674)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N. 1 is not grammatically correct. It would be:

> La película de los Vengadores es buena.

Which gives more positive feedback about the movie but both are equally correct to express that the movie was fine.

You were right saying that N.2 is your opinion and N.1 is a more authoritative answer, like a fact.