# "Estar" vs "ser" for a particular example

Tags: cópulas

In the following example (found in an example on one of language learning platforms), why ***ser*** is used instead of ***estar***?

> *Este mensaje es para el jefe.*

I know the differences that I've studied on different books, but I can't figure out the reason why in this particular example, ***ser*** is used.

Comment: Basically, it exists for the boss to read.  This is existential -- the message was created for the boss.  "Está" is good for location, emotional state, qualitative judgment, that sort of thing.

Comment: Welcome, Amir! We have a canonical question about the [differences between _ser_ and _estar_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/12637). Try to read it and see if it answers your question. If not, explain why and we'll try to answer your particular question and then add the information to the canonical one.

Comment: i think this is not a duplicate, I didn't see the explanation of this usage in those questions

Comment: @Charlie - It would be nice if our canonical q-a had something that includes this -- but I couldn't find anything.  (Maybe something should be added....)  Or, if you found something, could you share which part is relevant to OP's question?

Comment: I believe this part of the cannonical answer covers OP: "To talk about characteristics (that don't change so often) of things or persons"

Answer (score -2):

I think in this sentence both ***es*** (verb ***ser***) and ***está*** (verb ***estar***) can be used, but ***es*** is preferred.

Normally, when indicating ownership or delivery for something, we would use ***es***:

> This is for you.
>
> > *Esto **es** para ti.*

But when something is in a place or spot for it to be used then we use ***estar***:

> Why is the pen in the drawer?
>
> > *¿Por qué **está** la pluma en el cajón?*

In your example, if the message is written in paper taking a spot, then you **can** say:

> *Este mensaje **está** para el jefe.*

But if the message is something that is moving around, then it **HAS** to be:

> *Este mensaje **es** para el jefe.*

Other similar cases of ***estar***:

> I'm here to serve you.
>
> > ***Estoy*** aquí para servirle.
>
> The book is in the office.
>
> > *El libro **está** en la oficina.*

Another usage when you can use both ***ser*** and ***estar*** is when you are indicating a purpose:

> The pen is meant to be used.
>
> > *La pluma **es** para usarla.*
> >     *La pluma **está** para usarla.*

Comment: Did you know you can use the International Keyboard for accent marks? It's pretty hard to do Spanish without them. "The pen is to use it". What does that mean?? The Spanish is fine but the English would be: This pen is for being used.