# What's the difference between tengo and tienes?

Tags: definiciones

What's the difference between tengo and tienes and where can and should I use them? Also, what's the difference between esta and es? Where should I use these?

Comment: Have you searched this site? You second question is answered https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-are-the-differences-between-ser-and-estar-when-to-use-each-cu%c3%a1les here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se], and thank you for contributing a question! Unfortunately, in its current form, your question may get closed, as it lacks an explanation of what research you've done so far, focus about a single topic and clarity about what you don't understand. See [ask] to know more about how to post high quality questions that allow other users to understand what you need to know so they can help you. Visit [help] and [tour] to learn more about this site. Could you please [edit] the post to make your question clearer, so we can assist you? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"(Yo) tengo" is the first person singular, present tense, of the verb "tener".

"Tengo dos gatos": "I have two cats". "Tengo 30 años": "I'm 30 years old". "No tengo idea": "I have no clue".

"(Tú) tienes" is the second person, singular, present tense, of the same verb.

"Tienes dos gatos": "You have two cats".
"Tienes 30 años": "You are 30 years old".

You can see all the meanings of tener and how to conjugate it [here](https://dle.rae.es/tener?m=form#conjugaciongkyLET5).

About "esta" (I assume you really mean "está") and "es", you should ask a different question, but they are the verbs "estar" and "ser".