# What is the difference between estará vs será?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, futuro

Can someone explain the difference between these two in the future tense (examples would be very appreciated)? Since the future tense expresses uncertainty of the future, I am not sure how to interpret them.

Comment: Hi! Both of them refer to the future of the verb "to be". Take a look to this link where the difference is explained: https://langster.org/en/blog/ser-or-estar-difference-between-verbs-to-be-in-spanish/

Comment: It is just the difference between those two verbs which, although they both translate _to be_ are different in Spanish. A full explanation would occupy a book, can you give us a specific example which is puzzling you?

Comment: Hay una pregunta canónica que te puede orientar: [What are the differences between "ser" and "estar"? When to use each?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/6915). También puedes navegar por las preguntas con la tag ["ser-estar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%c3%b3pulas?tab=Votes).