# "Cuando era niño" or "cuando estaba niño"? How do I say "when I was a kid"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas

According to Duolingo, "when I was a kid" in Spanish is "cuando era niño" or "cuando era niña". Google Translate says the same thing.

That sounds strange to me. Being a kid is a temporary phase, not a fundamental part of who someone is, right? I would think it would use "estar", not "ser", and that "when I was a kid" would be "cuando estaba niño".

Do Spanish speakers use "era" or "estaba" for this? And if they use "era", why?

Comment: Pero en ese momento *eras* niñx. Si te hubieran preguntado en *esa* época, qué hubieses dicho? *Ser* niño es una cualidad mucho menos ‘temporal’ que *estar* triste. Tal vez la [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-are-the-differences-between-ser-and-estar-when-to-use-each-cu%c3%a1les) podría ayudar

Comment: Mas aún, te cito parte de la respuesta a la pregunta referenciada: *Ser is used when something has a quality it is expected to have, whereas estar is used when something has an unexpected quality*. De mi parte, nada más que agregar

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate? @tac, the one you linked to has a lot of stuff about "ser" and "estar" in general, but I don't see anything about why one or the other would be used in this situation.

Comment: I agree with @tac, I think that you're not going to find a better answer. If the answer does not satify you fully, let me offer a simpler approach: it's not idiomatic, we don't use estar in that context.

Comment: @EliasZamaria *Ser is used when something has a quality it is expected to have, whereas estar is used when something has an unexpected quality*. Te parece que 'ser niñx' es *an unexpected quality*?

Answer (score 1):

Although occasionally you can use "estar" associated to expressions related to age, like in:

> Estoy hecho un chaval

> Estoy viejo

These are expressions where speaker referes to it's personal perception of it's age, not an objective representation of it's true age. How old they **feel**, not how old they **are**

When you were a kid, you efectively **were** a kid, so you use "ser" and the correct expression would be

> Cuando era niño

If you wanted to express that in a previous moment in life, althoug being older, you **felt** like a youngster, you could use "estar"

> En aquella época **estaba** como un crío de 8 años (those days I was like an 8 years old child)

Comment: El último uso de *estar* parece ser más propio de España. Por lo menos acá se diría *era como un pibe de 8 años* en su lugar