# Usage of Estar and Ser

Tags: verbos

I'm learning Spanish with bussu and I came across this 2 sentences :

1- El miércoles **está** en mitad de la semana
2- El viernes **es** el día antes del fin de semana

Why in sentence 1 we used estar but in scentence 2 we used ser?
Shouldn't both be ser because we are stating a fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this [canonical question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/24236) with the main usage rules for *ser* and *estar*. In this case, the sentence

> El viernes es el día antes del fin de semana

uses *ser* because it is describing an inherent characteristic of the day Friday. The sentence

> El miércoles está en mitad de la semana

uses *estar* because it states the *location* of the day Wednesday within the week. Locations of places and things (but not of events!) are always stated with *estar*, even if they are inherent or permanent (e.g. "Viena está en Austria").